# Two way communication between providers in flutter provider package

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I try to update value from one provider to another in both direction. I already implemented  ChangeNotifierProxyProvider to update data from AuthProvider to FriendsProvider.

```
 class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
 }

 class FriendsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
 }

 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, FriendsProvider>(
            update: (context, value, previous) =>
                previous!..update(value.authToken, value.authUser),
            create: (context) => FriendsProvider(),
 ),
```

but I also want to update data in FriendsProvider from AuthProvider without recreating it.
How can I achieve this.